# Is it useful to use Auto Create Statistics = "ON" on a SQL Server 2005 DB?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

After restoring a large DB (70 Gb) from SQL Server 2000 onto a SQL Server 2005 Server we had encountered loss of performance while running queries, functions or procedures that on SQL Server 2000 worked ok.

After some troubleshooting we found that SQL Server Option "Auto Create Statistics" was ON, and after set it to OFF, the performance was improved very much.

Why was this option so bad to use in my case?

When is it OK to use Auto Create Statstistics = ON?

Thx

Comment: Yes it should pretty much always be set to on as the cost of inaccurate statistics can easily outweigh the cost of creating statistics. Did you actually trace the `AUTOSTATS` event to see how often it was fired and how long it was taking?

Comment: Also can you give a few more details of the performance problems you were experiencing? Once statistics are created on a column they won't need to be updated again until `X` number of data modifications are made (where `X` depends on the size of the table) so if you were finding that you were running the same queries and they didn't improve after the first run then I would question the diagnosis.

Comment: We saw the loss of performance specially on tables that were very large (10-25Gb) while filtering on NTEXT or Nvarchar(max) fields.

Comment: I think statistics on this type of column are indeed more time consuming to create as it creates a trie structure with details of the frequency of substrings but once created that should be a one time hit and you can turn off auto update on just those specific tables and schedule them to update out of hours. [UPDATE STATISTICS <table>...with NORECOMPUTE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195565)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really need to do is address *why* you are experiencing frequent statistic creation/update operations.

Did you update *ALL* of your statistics as part of your Upgrade process from SQL Server 2000 to 2005? You should have.

If you did not perform this as part of your upgrade process, then SQL will be creating the required statistics that it needs to perform your queries, as and when you execute them, when you have the AUTO CREATE STATS setting enabled. This of course creates resource overhead.

Comment: Yes i've updated all the statistics.
I did the following:
ReIndex
Update Stats with FUll Scan